# Multi column, multi row conditional duplicate removal

Tags: excel

Here's an example data set I have in Excel:

```
query   subject %identity   %RNA_identity   alignment_length    q.start q.end   s.start s.end
FN434113.1  CP001144.1  99.034  96.062  621 43828   44448   292720  293340
FN666575.1  CP001144.1  99.034  96.062  621 43828   44448   292720  293340
CP001144.1  FN434113.1  99.034  96.062  621 292720  293340  43828   44448
CP001144.1  FN666575.1  99.034  96.062  621 292720  293340  43828   44448
CP000352.1  CP001069.1  100 96.166  1289    33919   35207   63625   64913
CP001069.1  CP000352.1  100 96.166  1289    63625   64913   33919   35207
```

Row 2 and 4 are same with just colA and colB flipped.

Row 3 and 5 are same with just colA and colB flipped.

Row 6 and 7 are same with just colA and colB flipped.

What I intend to get is:

```
FN434113.1  CP001144.1  99.034  96.062  621 43828   44448   292720  293340
FN666575.1  CP001144.1  99.034  96.062  621 43828   44448   292720  293340
CP000352.1  CP001069.1  100 96.166  1289    33919   35207   63625   64913
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Based on the solution provided, I'm uploading the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1suihUvfkyGZLnBLQiWlxzHRPo5TEnooN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see my answer below. Let me know if you have questions. If this answers your question please check the green arrow by the answer to let future readers know.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The formula works for some cases, however, fails for some cases. I am providing the link to the excel file. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Thanks, which rows did it fail on? I was a little bit confused when I looked at it. Was the pink highlighting supposed to mean that the rows were not duplicates because they were different on the other column that's highlighted in pink?

Comment: Kindly see this file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1suihUvfkyGZLnBLQiWlxzHRPo5TEnooN/view?usp=sharing 
For example, rows 8-11, they are shown to be duplicated. Now base on column D values, there should be 2 unique rows out of 4 total rows.

Comment: Thank you, I have the file open, I just don't understand which rows didn't work. I also didn't understand if the highlighting meant something in cells D10 and D11 for example

Comment: Thank you. Considering rows 8-10: here if we consider just colA and colB, there is just one unique row. However, the values on colD show 2 sets, even if colA and colB are same. I highlighted them in blue and pink to show that they should be considered as separate rows. I hope I'm able to express the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve this, but the following formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)>1, "Here I am! I'm a duplicate!","Original")
```

was used in a similar problem here:

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-formulas-to-find-multi-column-duplicates-in-excel/

I imported your data and mapped it the cells of your data and made an improvement to the logic so that it is not sensitive to the order of the 2 columns. Seems to work fine on your data:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:B4,B4)>1, COUNTIF($A$2:B4,A4)>1), "Here I am! I'm a duplicate!","Original")
```

Note that the start row is 2 because of the header. The 4 (i.e. B4) is just an arbitrary example row I copied the formula from.
[image]